# How to clean object on insert

Tags: meteor

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this. It's quite possible I'm using the wrong terminology so feel free to correct me and put me on the right path.

I'm using to using a plugin called simple-schema with meteor that cleaned, `null` or `""` fields when you used insert to create a document. See below.

Uncleaned document

```
{
  "_id": "f3iujiimjHo4m3Cqj",
  "monday": true,
  "tuesday": ""
}
```

Cleaned document

```
{
  "_id": "f3iujiimjHo4m3Cqj",
  "monday": true
}
```

I can't find anything on how this is done. Can someone please tell me what I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use obj-clean to do this.

install

```
meteor npm install --save obj-clean
```

Usage

```
import clean = from 'obj-clean'

const dirty = {
  "_id": "f3iujiimjHo4m3Cqj",
  "monday": true,
  "tuesday": ""
}

const cleaned = clean(dirty)
```

Thats it, more on the [npm package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/obj-clean)